# How do I know if a number can be obtained by incrementing by 4 starting from 1?

Tags: c, algorithm

I need to know if a number can be obtained by incrementing 1 by 4 iteratively. Those numbers are 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, etc. For this, I am presently doing the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int number = 13;
  int i;
  for (i = n; i > 0; i -= 4) {
    if (i == 1) {
      printf("yes\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i <= 0)
    printf("no\n");
}
```

But this seems to be extremely inefficient O(n) approach. I would appreciate an O(1) solution for this, can I do better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator:

`if ( num % 4 == 1 ) printf("yep")`;

Comment: There was no mention of a language, nor whether there is a modulus operator.

Comment: @Ingo #include <stdio.h> <- kinda gives it away doesn't it..?

Comment: @IanKenney: How, on earth, could I forget the modulus operator? :-o Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jonas It is actually overkill to do an expensive division in this case. However, it is the more generic solution if the divisor is not a power of 2. And the compiler will hopefully optimize it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you want to check if a number `n` is of the form

```
n = 1+4k
```

so you just need to check if its predecessor is evenly divisible by 4.

If you have binary 2's complement numbers, the latter is the case if the last 2 bits are 0.

Hence:

```
int check(int n) { return (n-1)&3 == 0; }
```

To get hat even shorter, a number of the form `1+4k` will have the last two bits a s`01`:

```
    int check(int n) { return n&3 == 1; }
```

Comment: +1 for extremely efficient, compiler-optimization independent solution!

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1 and make a modulo division by 4. If 0 is the result you have a match.

Comment: Why subtract 1 when he can just check for 1 as the remainder? :)

Comment: Comes out the same, sure. The important bit is not to use a loop if it comes to performance.

Comment: @arkascha: How, on earth, could I forget the modulus operator? :-o Thanks! :)